# No preset found on channel 9 when playing midi with newly created soundfont

Tags: audio, midi, soundfont, fluidsynth

I have created a soundfont with Polyphone to create a new instrument "bagana".

It just has 1 instrument "Bagana", with 1 present "Bagana".

I tried playing a midi file (just a piano piece) with FluidSynth, it worked. When I direct it through the new soundfront it says:

```
fluidsynth: warning: No preset found on channel 9 [bank=128 prog=0]
```

Is there a problem with the soundfont not being loaded?

[This is the sf2 file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/bagana.sf2) and [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/Reunion_Example.mid) and [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13564139/tew.mid) are the midi files I am trying to play.

I am running the midi with this command:

```
>>fluidsynth -C0 -R1 -l -a alsa -F out.wav ./bagana.sf2 /home/dorien/UA/projects/bagana/Reunion_Example.mid
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For General MIDI compatibility, the default sound font instrument assignments are bank 0, program 0 ("Acoustic Grand Piano") for channels 0–8 and 10–15, and bank 128, program 0 ("Default Drum Set") for channel 9.

Apparently, your sound font does not have the latter.

This does not matter if your MIDI file does not assume General MIDI compatible instruments and does not try to play drum sounds on channel 9.

Comment: Still strange, because I am trying with a normal acoustic grand piano file (see question for the .mid) and it is still giving me the channel 9 error.

Comment: fluidsynth initializes all channel's instruments before it reads the .mid file.

Comment: Fixed it. So in my soundfont I added a preset with bank 128, channel 0 and put my instrument there. I had it on bank 0, channel 0 before. I am uncertain what would be the correct bank/channel to use to create a new instrument not in the midi list. And if it is ok that the soundfont doesn't have other instruments for the rest? Thank you for pointing me in the right direction before!

Comment: @dorien I encountered the same problem in fluidsynth. I tried to download soundfont about drums on the internet, but It still reported an error when running. I want to ask, how do you specifically solve this problem? Or are there any related links